# Referencing C++ UWP project

Tags: c++, uwp

(I can see several other similar questions on SO, but not this exact combination)

How do I add reference of a UWP (C++) project in other project types? I tried UWP (C#) and WinForms (.NET 4.5) projects and both of them freak out saying:

> > A reference to '[C++ Project Name]' could not be added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on exactly what you mean by a UWP (C++) project, you cant. UWP C++ projects don't use .Net and so don't generate .Net assemblies.

You can create a [Windows Runtime Component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh441572.aspx) (WRC) in C++ and add reference it in a UWP C# (or JavaScript) project, but not in a WinForms project.

See [Walkthrough: Creating a basic Windows Runtime component in C++ and calling it from JavaScript or C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh755833.aspx)

Once it's referenced the classes defined in the WRC will project into the C# app and be callable like any other C# class.

You could also create a C++ DLL, include it in the project, and then p-invoke it from either a UWP or WinForms app. There isn't any automatic wiring for this scenario: you'll need to write the pinvoke definitions, etc. yourself.

Comment: OK. It probably makes sense for WinForms, but why can't I add C++ (UWP) project's reference to C# (UWP)? They both should be talking in the same language, no?

Comment: C# and C++ are different languages. C# uses .Net. C++ does not. To use them together requires a interop layer: pinvoke or a winmd (WRC). Add reference understands .Net and Winmds but not standard C++ DLLs.

Comment: Thanks. WRC was a great hint. I am still a bit confused about C++ (Universal) project. My understanding was that C++ (Universal) is similar to C# (Universal) and VB.NET (Universal) projects with regard to the platform they target (UWP that is); and that it was just a matter of language one prefers to code in.